# My system won't boot after reboot

Tags: hardware, reboot

I recently assembled the following system:

**MOBO:**   TRX40 AORUS PRO WIFI (1.0)

**GPUs:**   2x EVGA FTW3 ULTRA GAMING RTX 3090

**CPU:**    Threadripper 3990x

**OS:**     Ubuntu Server 20.04

**RAM:**    Corsair CMK256GX4M8D3600C18

**PSU:**    EVGA SuperNOVA 1600 T2

After several attempts now, if I turn on my system, I can log into my OS. But if from the OS itself I reboot, then the motherboard hangs. The only way I can debug what the mobo is doing is through 4 LEDs, which should light up sequentially, each indicating the corresponding component is checked and working:
CPU -> DRAM -> VGA -> Boot. On the motherboard I can see that it hangs on DRAM LED. If then I force a shutdown through the power button, and power the system back on, than everything works fine. Also if I shutdown the system from OS, and then wake it up via the power button, it works fine. The only issue seems to be when I reboot. I tried clearing CMOS removing the small battery but does not solve this issue. Also tried a different type of memory stick. Also tried running the system with a single stick. None of this helped. Any suggestion? The only thing I can think of is a faulty mobo.

Comment: As long as people keep buying these motherboards, vendors will never bother to ship less buggy firmware.. put the RAM clocks to safe defaults and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Sadly that's something I've already tested by disabling any XMP profiles. Do you think I should increase manually RAM timings? Anyway I've ordered an MSI TRX40 Pro 10G (which allows better debugging  in any case) to see if I'm simply working with a defective MOBO.